# Uncaught Exception in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a very simple line of code that is querying for the List only the first 20 names of companies with offices in either California or Texas, ordered by the number of employees and sorted largest to smallest.

My query looks like this:

```
db.research.find({"$or": [{"state_code": "TX"},{"state_code":"CA"}]},{"name":1,"_id": 0}).sort("number_of_employees":-1).limit(20)
```

When I run this code I get this uncaught exception: SyntaxError:

```
2020-12-18T15:57:42.409+0000 E QUERY [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list : @(shell):1:116
```

I cannot for the life of me find the missing ")". Is the error message giving me this SyntaxError due to another part of the code being incomplete?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: .sort missing brackets ```.sort({"number_of_employees":-1})```

Comment: Thank you for that! I added that and the error message was resolved! However, now I don't get any output. I suspect this is due to an incorrect search key from my database.